# Issue with python's web3 module: why is web3.isConnected() always returning false?

Tags: python, web3py

I'm trying to get acquainted with python's web3 class, and I cannot seem to get connected to infura's node using my API. The isConnected() function always returns false, no matter what.

```
from web3 import Web3, eth

infura_url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/' + my_api_key
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(infura_url))
print (w3.isConnected())
```

Always returns **false**. And if I can't connect to the ethereum network, I can't run fucntions on contracts etc. It's a problem :(

Answer (score 0):

**There is two possiblity**

*one* :
you need to check api key

*two* :
maybe the chain you got it doesnt provide method name start as `eth`
web3 default method naming as `eth`, every method start like this `eth_transfer`
so when you wanna check this possiblity, you can call method like `print(w3.isConnected())`
go infura [dashboard](https://infura.io/dashboard/stats) and check your requests volumn.
if your request was accepted but respond as false, it might be means that method name start different